# ios amazon s3 uploading video file

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, video, upload

SOS, i need help. I did image uploading on to Amazon S3, and it's working fine, but when I rewrite this code for uploading video it's somethink wrong. Is uploading MOV file, but when i try to play it on browser from url, it's telling me: The image https... cannot be displayed because it contains error.

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL) startMediaBrowserFromViewController: (UIViewController*) controller
                           usingDelegate: (id <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                                           UINavigationControllerDelegate>) delegate{
// Get image picker
UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
mediaUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;
mediaUI.delegate = delegate;

// Display movie files
[controller presentModalViewController:mediaUI animated:YES ];

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
UIImage *image = (UIImage*) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];    

fileName = "anyName.MOV";
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

@try {
    S3PutObjectRequest *por = [[S3PutObjectRequest alloc] initWithKey:fileName inBucket:MY_BUCKET];
    por.contentType = @"movie/mov";
    por.cannedACL   = [S3CannedACL publicRead];
    por.data        = imageData;
    [s3 putObject:por];
}

@catch (AmazonClientException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"exception %@", exception);
}
}
```

Pleas point me on my mistake.

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Which library do you import from AWSSDK to access S3PutObjectRequest?

Comment: for the MY_BUCKET  what did u use ? coz i get   AmazonServiceException { RequestId:C25210BBC515D041, ErrorCode:NoSuchBucket, Message:The specified bucket does not exist }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorted. Problem was with Image object. So I just did get video URL by :

```
NSURL *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
```

Instead

```
UIImage *image = (UIImage*) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

And then pass NSData from url, so I did replace line

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

to:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:image];
```

And tataaaaaaaa, problem sorted.